# Moving SharePoint 2007 Lists/Lookups between subsites within same site collection

Tags: 2007, list, lookup-column, site-collection, sub-site

We have a list 'Leaders' that we want to move from one subsite (A) to subsite (B) that is in the same site collection. I had gone into 'Site Actions' -> 'Site Settings'-> 'Modify All Site Settings' -> Under 'Site Administration' -> 'Site Libraries and Lists', the list 'Leaders' reside here. From here I selected 'Leaders' and created a list template and saved it as 'Leaders'. Saved the list to my desk top from the template file that was created, then uploaded it to site (B) via 'Create New Content' (by following the above steps to get to 'Create New Content' from the lists for (B).

The only issue that I am finding is that the data within this list, the leaders names and info, didn't move over. What am I missing? Is this something I can do in 2007?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you check the check box Include Content while creating a list template?

Comment: Yes I did, but I did figure out what the issue was. There was a 'Target Audience' that needed to be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out! Yes, you can move lists from one subsite to another in SP07, just make sure the target audience is empty or only contains who/groups that need to be targeted and add yourself. To do this, go to 'Site Actions' -> 'Edit Page'-> then select 'edit' -> 'Modify Shared Webpart' -> 'Advanced' -> and if there are any targeted audiences remove them or if you need them, add yourself or any other audiences that need to be targeted.